# spring HTTP Status 404

Tags: spring

eclipse 2020-03, spring 5.0.2, java 1.8.0_91

при запуске хеловорда - ошибка 404, а именно:

```
SEVERE: Servlet [dispatcher] in web application [/spring-mvc-demo] threw load() exception
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
```

все jar spring'а лежат в WEB-INF/lib

кто сталкивался с подобной про блемой, подскажите, в чём может быть ошибка?

[image: топология]

## web.xml

```
<display-name>spring-mvc-demo</display-name>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-mvc-demo-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

## spring-mvc-demo-servlet.xml

```
<context:component-scan base-package="net.test.springdemo" />

<mvc:annotation-driven/>

<bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/view/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>
```

## DefaultController

```
package net.test.springdemo;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class DefaultController {
    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String showDefaultPage() {
        return "default-page";
    }

}
```

Comment: у вас не подключена библиотека, в которой есть класс `org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet`

Comment: а какая библиотека обеспечивает этот класс ? spring скачан отсюда https://repo.spring.io/release/org/springframework/spring/5.0.2.RELEASE/ и все библиотеки положил в WEB-INF/lib

Comment: `spring-webmvc`. Собирайте проект хотя бы через maven

Comment: spring-webmvc-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar присутствует WEB-INF/lib

Comment: значит зависимости должны лежать в другом каталоге. Ваш `WEB-INF/lib` не интересен

Comment: сконвертировал в maven проект, он собрался buid success, потом делаю run as -> run on server, и опять такая же ошибка

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11227395/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-org-springframework-web-servlet-dispatcherserv

Comment: установил jdk и указал его в execution enviroment, до этого был jre